# Assigning a new value to array of key=>value when the value has already been set

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am working with translations in Laravel and I have several arrays with translation keys that map to their corresponding translation. I need to remove any translation that has a `--` and replace it with an empty string. I am already doing some other str-replacements in the same function so maybe I'm clobbering the function.

Here is what the entire function looks like:

```
public function getWithContext($locale, $context)
{
    $this->registerContext($context);

    $contextKey = "{$locale}.{$context}";

    if ($this->has($contextKey)) return $this->get($contextKey);

    $out = [];

    $data = $this->get($locale);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (preg_match("/^({$context}\.)/", $key)) {
            $k       = str_replace("{$context}.", "", $key); 
            $out[$k] = ($value == "—-") ? "" : $value;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($out)) {
        $this->put($contextKey, new Collection($out));
    }

    return $out;
}
```

I'm trying to get the line `$out[$k] = ($value == "--") ? "" : $value;` to work specifically.

Comment: What's not working ? Do you have an error, or is assignment not working ? What's in you `$out` var ?

Comment: I wasn't getting an error, it just wasn't changing the dashes to an empty string as I expected it to.  I posted what happened in an answer below. Thanks for asking and trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this has anything to do with it but in your question you mentioned the string `"--"` but in your code the string is `"—-"` which has a different character for the first dash

Comment: That's exactly the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. The encoding of the dashes that are entered through my keyboard are different than what the server sees. Therefore I had to copy the values from the server into the code and it worked perfectly.